# Restricting Django-Rest-Framework default CRUD operations to only GET and restricting POST, PUT and DELETE

Tags: django, api, rest, http-post

I am using Django-Rest-Framework. While following along the tutorial I was able to make CRUD APIs by defining a ModelResource. Now, I want to limit access by providing APIs for just GET and not provide access for POST, PUT or DELETE.
I tried

```
allowed_methods = ('GET')
```

But that doesn't do anything. Also, I tried to override the delete function of ModelResource but it doesn't do anything either and delete still works.

Seems to be straight forward thing, but I havent been able to figure it out even after spending a couple of hours on it.

Comment: Can you provide more source code? Like your class declaration and/or your url pattern?

Answer (score 3):

Just saw this. You have a small error in your code. Instead of:

```
 allowed_methods = ('GET')
```

Write

```
allowed_methods = ('GET',)
```

Note the trailing comma, this is to make python treat it as a list with one string instead of a list with three characters. Due to the fact that python treats a string as a list of characters, the first row evaluates to the list `('G','E','T')` and none of those methods are available on your class.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using something like this:

resources.py

```
from djangorestframework.resources import ModelResource

from .models import Menu


class MenuResource(ModelResource):
    model = MenuOfTheDay
    allowed_methods = ('GET', )
```

urls.py

```
from djangorestframework.views import ListOrCreateModelView, InstanceModelView

from .resources import MenuResource


urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^api/menu/$', ListOrCreateModelView.as_view(resource=MenuResource), name='menu-resource-root'),
    url(r'^api/menu/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', InstanceModelView.as_view(resource=MenuResource)),
)
```

**allowed_methods** won't be useful if is in a Resource subclass, it should be in a View subclass like in **ListModelView** class, so if you change your urls.py with this:

```
from djangorestframework.views import ListModelView, InstanceModelView

from .resources import MenuResource


urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^api/menu/$', ListModelView.as_view(resource=MenuResource), name='menu-resource-root'),
    url(r'^api/menu/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', InstanceModelView.as_view(resource=MenuResource)),
)
```

it will work fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
from djangorestframework.mixins import ReadModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin
from djangorestframework.views import ModelView
from djangorestframework.response import Response

from resources import MyResource

class MyResourceInstanceView(ReadModelMixin, ModelView):
  resource = MyResource
```

Basicaly this is replacing the use of `InstanceModelView`, which implements also the `Put`, `Update` and `Delete` mixins.